# Eclipse run my program well however JAR-file does not

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar, nullpointerexception

I have four classes in my game; Player.java, Game.java, Island.java and Map.java. And basically its plenty of code to link here however my issue is that my program works fine in eclipse but when i export as jar and run it nothing is opened so i open it with CMD and it gives errors.

Input in CMD:

```
java -jar GameAlliansen.jar
```

Output from CMD:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon.

This is how i import my images

```
 island = new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("/Island(64x64).png"));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T2Nv.png Thats my image of project

Comment: 1. Is the file included in the jar? 2. Does it have the correct capitalization?

Comment: @Lurr123 see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532114/how-to-package-images-into-a-runnable-jar) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java)

Comment: has *Island(64x64).png* been exported in the jar file? if what is its location in the jar file?

Comment: More examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: Ill post how my organisation is done.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dRe2HNz.png

Comment: I just do the export with runnable and just simple jar however noone works.

Comment: Also they seem kind of small, just 59KB? That cant be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
Icon island =new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Island(64x64).png")));
```

Comment: Changed, same problem works in eclipse but not when i run outside eclipse as the runnable jar

Answer (score 1):

The paths inside jars are case sensitive, whereas not all filesystems are (such as the one used by Windows is just case preserving, not case sensitive). You're trying to load "Island(64x64).png", but the image shows the actual filename is "island(64x64).png". Change these to match.

Answer (score 0):

When you export it, create a folder in which you will put your jar file and ALSO the image Island(64x64).png

Comment: Well, i wanted to not need to do that, i mean simply include images in the JAR to be able to upload it so people can download just one single file